# Neo4j Creating a relationship conditionally based on one of the property of node

Tags: neo4j

I need to create two different type of relationship between two nodes. Type of relationship depends upon one of the property of the node.

For Example,

I have two nodes USER and EVENT. I have two relationships to create between them. 
 1. invite
 2. requestToInvite

Even node has property inviteOnly.

Create a "Invite" relationship if inviteOnly is true. Otherwise create "requestToInvite" relationship.

This is what i am trying:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ID(u) = 13
WITH u
MATCH (e:Events)
WHERE ID(e) = 0
WITH u,e
CREATE (u)-[:inviteONLYTrue]->(e) WHERE e.inviteOnly = true
CREATE (u)-[:inviteONLYFALSE]->(e) WHERE e.inviteOnly = false
WITH u,e
RETURN u,e
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no conditional but you can work around it by iterating over a zero or one-element list which is created by a CASE statement.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE ID(u) = 13
MATCH (e:Events) WHERE ID(e) = 0
FOREACH (_ in case e.inviteOnly when true then [1] else [] end |
  CREATE (u)-[:inviteONLYTrue]->(e) )
FOREACH (_ in case e.inviteOnly when false then [1] else [] end |
  CREATE (u)-[:inviteONLYFALSE]->(e) )
RETURN u,e
```

Comment: You made my Day... Thank you.

Comment: Yup, saved the day :-D

Answer (score 2):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) just updated with support for conditional cypher execution, but in this particular case all you'll need is a way to create a relationship with a dynamic relationship type. APOC has a procedure for this too. Here's an example:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ID(u) = 13
WITH u
MATCH (e:Events)
WHERE ID(e) = 0
WITH u,e, CASE WHEN e.inviteOnly THEN 'inviteONLYTrue' ELSE 'inviteONLYFALSE' END as relType
CALL apoc.create.relationship(u, relType, {}, e) YIELD rel
RETURN u,e
```